# Как объявить массив объектов класса, если конструктор имеет параметры?

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, динамические-массивы

Подскажите, как объявить массив объектов класса, если конструктор класса имеет параметры?

```
//Прототип констуктора
Individ(int num);
```

Другой класс:

```
class Genalg
{
private:
    Individ *generation;
    int size_genom;
    int size_generation;
public:
    dec_generation ()
    {
        generation = new Individ [size_generation];
    }
```

При компиляции g++ выдаёт что не существует функции Individ без параметов, пытаюсь где то вставить скобку с параметрами наподобие `generation = new Individ (size_genom) [size_generation];`, компилятор говорит, что после круглых скобок должна быть ";".
Как правильно объявить такой массив?

Answer (score 4):

Если бы размер массива был фиксированный, то можно было бы написать `new MyClass[N]{...};`. Для массива переменного размера это теряет смысл, потому что непонятно, сколько элементов писать в скобках.

Не стоит использовать `new` и `delete`, если только вы не пишете свой контейнер или умный указатель. Лучше использовать готовый контейнер - `std::vector`. Это не только решит проблему с конструктором, но и позволит не думать от ручном освобождении памяти:

```
std::vector<Individ> generation;
```

Тогда добавление элемента с с нужными аргументами конструктора выглядит так:

```
generation.emplace_back(...);
```

А если нужно много элементов, то так:

```
generation.assign(N, Individ(...));
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужна особая форма оператора `new` **с размещением** (placement new). То есть вы размещаете объект по указанному в первой скобке адресу:

```
//выделим необходимую память    
generation = static_cast<Individ*>(
    operator new [](size_generation * sizeof(Individ)));
//разместим объекты по указателям(на свое место)
for (int i = 0; i < size_generation; ++i)
    //placement new
    new (generation + i)  Individ(0);
//...
```

**Обновил**:

да, `maestro` прав, нужно было еще и написать как освобождать память.
Тут нужно учесть, что мы не выделяли память под конкретные объекты, поэтому их деструктор не будет вызван. Деструкторы нужно вызвать в ручную:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size_generation; ++i)
     generation[i].~Individ();
```

А уж потом освобождать все куски, на что указывает generation:

```
operator delete[](generation);
```

Comment: Здесь `i` разве на единицу надо наращивать? Не на `sizeof(individ)`?

Comment: Неплохо было бы ещё написать, как их потом удалять.

Comment: @maestro,  память выделена  для size_generation штук объектов  Individ, указатель   generation указывает на первый кусок, и конечно надо наращивать на единицу

Comment: @maestro, по поводу удаления согласен _  важный момент, и я  дописал.

Comment: да, я проверил, действительно надо на единицу.